# Increment a value for each loop

Tags: loops, ansible, jinja2

I want to increment an integer value over the loop for each item in variable in a jinja template

This is my variable:

```yaml
variable: {"config1", "config2"}
```

This is the task I use to copy the template out

```yaml
    - name: Templating 
      vars:
        offset: 1000
      template:
        src: "/var/opt/file.j2"
        dest: "/var/opt/file"
      with_list: "{{ variable }}"
      loop_control:
        index_var: index
```

And this is my `file.j2` template

```
{% for item in variable %}
  configuration_{{ item }}:
    value:
    - {{ index + offset }}
    path:
    - /var/opt/{{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

I want to get something for each item in the list variable that looks like the following:

```yaml
 configuration_config1:
    value:
    - 100
    path:
    - /var/opt/config1
 configuration_config2:
    value:
    - 101
    path:
    - /var/opt/config2
```

But my current implementation does not give the expected result.

Comment: 1) you are not providing your input data structure (i.e. `variable`), we can only guess what it looks like. 2) You are looping twice on the same var in the task and in the template. Do you want one overall file result or one file for each value in `variable` ? (solutions are different) 3) The resulting yaml structure from your template is not valid: you have a duplicate key (i.e. `configuration:`) and only the last defined one will be retained, Also, `value` and `path` being lists is a bit suspicious. Please don't answer in comments: [edit your question](/posts/68814676/edit)

Comment: Please do not edit your post if you have another question. Ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have several lines in the same template file, you should not loop in your task but in your template only.

In this case, you should refer to the [Jinja2 `for` structure documentation](https://jinja2docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/templates.html#for) and use the corresponding special variables available inside the loop.

Given the following `file.j2` template

```
{% for item in my_var %}
configuration_{{ item }}:
  value:
    - {{ loop.index + offset | default(0) | int }}
  path:
    - /var/opt/{{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

And the following `play.yml` playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    my_var:
      - aconfig
      - otherconfig
      - lastconfig

    offset: 100

  tasks:

    - name: show the template result as a debug output
      debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('template', 'file.j2').split('\n') }}"

    - name: actually write the output file on disk
      template:
        src: file.j2
        dest: /tmp/trash_it.yaml
```

We get:

```
# Run the playbook with configured offset in vars
$ ansible-playbook play.yml

PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [show the template result as a debug output] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "configuration_aconfig:",
        "  value:",
        "    - 101",
        "  path:",
        "    - /var/opt/aconfig",
        "configuration_otherconfig:",
        "  value:", 
        "    - 102",
        "  path:",
        "    - /var/opt/otherconfig",
        "configuration_lastconfig:",
        "  value:",
        "    - 103",
        "  path:",
        "    - /var/opt/lastconfig",
        ""
    ]
}

TASK [actually write the output file on disk] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

# Demo it works for any value overriding the offset in an extra var
$ ansible-playbook play.yml -e offset=583

PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [show the template result as a debug output] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "configuration_aconfig:",
        "  value:",
        "    - 584",
        "  path:",
        "    - /var/opt/aconfig",
        "configuration_otherconfig:",
        "  value:", 
        "    - 584",
        "  path:",
        "    - /var/opt/otherconfig",
        "configuration_lastconfig:",
        "  value:",
        "    - 585",
        "  path:",
        "    - /var/opt/lastconfig",
        ""
    ]
}

TASK [actually write the output file on disk] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: thanks very much it works, I spend very much to try it !!

Comment: thanks for helping, I edit the question because, I have a new question :)

Comment: Just to let you know: I edited my answer so it fits your revised output requirement. I also edited your question to fix the formatting, add some clarity and remove the subsidiary question that you should put in a new one. You can still access the removed content looking at the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68814676/revisions) if you need to.